# PyTelegramBotApi. Как принимать несколько сообщений от пользователя

Tags: python, telebot

хотелось бы понять как мне можно реализовать: Человек пишет число(5) и бот спрашивает человека 5 раз сохраняя все ответы, через register_next_step_handler() не понял как это можно нормально реализовать, Бот нужен для того что бы репостить записи в vk.com. Пример кода:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

from Project import main
from Project import open_repost
from Project import window_post

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


def subscrite_public(message):
    ->     <---- Код
    

def solution(message):
    if message.text == 'Да':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите кол-во ссылок')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, subscrite_public)
        
    else:
        pass

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

def start(message):
    global text_user
    text_user = message.text
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    button1 = types.KeyboardButton('Да')
    button2 = types.KeyboardButton('Нет')
    markup.add(button1, button2)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты хочешь продолжить?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, solution)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я отредактировал ваш код, бот записывает сообщение по ключу в словаре, который выводится в консоли программы. После каждого записанного сообщения боту, пользователю снова даём выбрать записать ли ещё одно сообщение, пока пользователь не нажмёт кнопку Нет, при которой мы выводим словарь полученных сообщений

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

all_messages = {}
count_urls = [0]

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    global text_user
    text_user = message.text
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    button1 = types.KeyboardButton('Да')
    button2 = types.KeyboardButton('Нет')
    keyboard.add(button1, button2)
    if count_urls[0] > 0:
        all_messages[len(all_messages) + 1] = message.text
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сообщение записано\nТы хочешь продолжить?', reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, solution)
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты хочешь продолжить?', reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, solution)


def solution(message):
    if message.text == 'Да':
        count_urls[0] += 1
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите сообщение')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ':(')
        print(all_messages)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```